# How to set the upstream branch for new local branch with JGit

Tags: eclipse, git, jgit

I use the following code to create a new branch from `origin/master`:

```java
CreateBranchCommand branchCmd = git.branchCreate();
branchCmd.setForce(true);
branchCmd.setName("newFeatureBranch");
branchCmd.setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM);
branchCmd.setStartPoint("origin/master");
branchCmd.call();
```

After running this code I get a new local branch with the following upstream:

[image]

But that is not what I want. Its upstream should be set to `refs/heads/newFeatureBranch`:

[image]

How do I set the upstream in the new branch?

Comment: Don't you need to do this: `branchCmd.setStartPoint("origin/newFeatureBranch");`

Comment: That is only possible to I first create and push that branch, but maybe thats just how its done.

Comment: If you didn't create and push the branch yet you could try with `branchCmd.setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK);
  branchCmd.setStartPoint("origin/newFeatureBranch");`